# How to play a .MKV 3D Video on my 3DTV?

Tags: dvd, conversion, streaming, matroska, 3d

I have a 3D movie on my computer hard drive. I've tried to stream it to my TV but that does'nt work because of the .MKV extension, so how do I play it on my TV? Can I burn it to DVD? Do I have to convert it to another format? Or do I put it on my portable hardrive and connect it directly to my TV? I'm confused!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing to do with the MKV extension. Your player must currently understand it's a 3D image and send the correct info to the graphics driver which will have to send the correct info over HDMI (assuming you're using HDMI).

Encoding-wise, there's nothing special about 3D videos. The most common form is just two images side-by-side. You'll probably have to manually set some option to tell your player that the video is in 3D.

Also, you can't play 3D over DVI or VGA unless your TV explicitly supports it.

The only software I know that claim to support 3D over a range of graphics technology is PowerDVD, but I have never tried it.